# How can I create an array that I can call a specific 'card' from? (it makes sense in the post)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to create some sort of card game in python but I can't get past a pretty crucial part of the design-designing the card faces as callable objects. I have my array of just heart cards below (I tried to divide the card suits into 4 different functions because I can't figure out how to make it one function) but when I try to print the art it comes out all in one line.

```
heartsArt = {

1 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 1 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),  
2 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 2 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
3 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 3 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
4 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 4 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
5 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 5 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
6 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 6 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
7 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 7 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),
8 : (
    '┌───┐',
    '| 8 |',
    '└───┘',
  ),  
}

cardHeight = len(heartsArt[1])
cardLength = len(heartsArt[1][0])
cardFaceSeparator = ''

def generateHeartFace(cardValues):
  cardFaces = []
  for x in cardValues:
    cardFaces.append(heartsArt[x])

  for xID in range(cardHeight):
    rowComp = []
    for card in cardFaces:
      rowComp.append(heartsArt[card])      #line 57
    rowString = cardFaceSeparator.join(rowComp)
    cardFaceRows.append(rowString)


generateHeartFace([1])   #line 62
```

The error that comes up is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "script.py", line 62 in <module> generateHeartFace([1])
  File "script.py", line 57, in generateHeartFace
        rowComp.append(heartsArt[card])
  KeyError: ('┌───┐', '| 1 |', '└───┘')
```

If someone could please explain both/either why my code doesn't work, or how I could make it work it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes that was a typo, but it still doesn't work even when I fixed that

Comment: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` means you are treating an integer like it is a list (or other iterable). Ex: `x = 3; x[0]`. Add the full error message. It should say what line the error is on.

Comment: `generateHeartArt(1)` I assume that is another typo since the function is called `generateHeartFace`. Anyway, `1` is not iterable, which you are attempting to treat as such at `for x in cardValues:`. Try `generateHeartFace([1])`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'll just add my entire code... once sec

Comment: At `rowComp.append(heartsArt[card]) `, `card` is a tuple. You want `rowComp.append(card[xID])`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ok I think that works now since no errors pop up anymore... What would I have to add to ```print``` the card at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've answered all your questions in the comments. Here's your code working:

```
def generateHeartFace(cardValues):
  cardFaces = []
  for x in cardValues:
    cardFaces.append(heartsArt[x])

  cardFaceRows = []
  for xID in range(cardHeight):
    rowComp = []
    for card in cardFaces:
      rowComp.append(card[xID])      #line 57
    rowString = cardFaceSeparator.join(rowComp)
    cardFaceRows.append(rowString)

  print('\n'.join(cardFaceRows))
```

Don't forget to pass an iterable:

```
generateHeartFace([1,2,3])
```

And here's another way to do it that does not require the `heartsArt` dictionary:

```
def generateHeartFace(cardValues):
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join("┌───┐" * len(cardValues)))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join(f"| {c} |" for c in cardValues))
    print(cardFaceSeparator.join("└───┘" * len(cardValues)))
```

Comment: Oh wow I really over complicated that... thanks for actually explaining how to make my code work before linking the easy way though. I think I actually understand what is going on now